# Which  is faster to retrieve data using WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a .net application and want to access the database at my website.

Which one is faster to retrieve the data?

1. connect the database directly from my .net application?
2. using third party like php that return the xml/json?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about speed, it depends on what you want to do.  If you make a connection, want to retrieve 1000 records, do some special work to filter them (that can't be moved to the SQL query), then finally only work with 3 records, a webservice that does this for you will be faster because you only need to download 3 records from the server, not all 1000.

However, from a security perspective, client applications shouldn't directly connect to the database anyway.

You don't even necessarily need to use a "third party like php".  Take a look at WCF services for C#.NET applications.

That all said, it's difficult to comment with any kind of certainty or specificity since you aren't specific about what you're exactly wanting to do with your application.

Comment: eventhough my database is online at my web?

Comment: Well I suppose that depends on your web host then.  Still, this is largely dependent on the amount/type of data being transferred and how big of an issue security is. (are you the only one using this program, or do you plan on distributing it?)

Comment: exactly i'm still develop the app for one restaurant. But maybe next time want to distribute it. If i want to distribute it, thats mean i must have a server for their data, and they will retrieve the data from my server? is that true?

Comment: YOu tell us - depends how you organize it. But ingeneral the diference will jot be noticable - the network overhead will hide it.

Comment: I am with these guys. If you are writing you application to be scalable, you should avoid 2 layer architecture. A WCF service as a business layer is a good approach. But remember, for every layer of abstraction you add, the more latency (no matter how minute) you create as well.

If you are really sold on 2-layer and want a quick implementation with some bells and whistles, I would look into RIA services for WCF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344(v=vs.91).aspx. I personally do not use them but this could work for your needs.

Comment: I also considering about the WCF. and test it already but using sql server. still failed if my database is at my web hosting.